# Simplification of the boolean expression

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

The following is the logic circuit:
[image]

I have to simplify the following:

(((AB)')'+(B+C)+(AB)'(B+C)')C

=(AB+B+C+(A'+B')(B'C'))C

=(B+C+A'B'C'+B'C')C

=BC+C+A'B'C+B'C

=C+A'BC'+B'C

Comment: Draw a truth table for both - the original and the result. Compare. Note that the final expression can be further simplified.

Comment: Actually I'm given a logic circuit and have to simplify the expression in order to get the truth table.

Comment: You can get a truth table from a non-simplified expression. This one is a bit complicated, but not a big deal. You can fill up half of it right away noting the AND with C of the whole expression.

Comment: Unless I'm reading the parenthesis wrong, the answer is just C. Everything is or'ed with that inner C + B, then and'd with C. Are you sure you copied it down correctly?

Comment: @yhyrcanus  I added the logic circuit and made some changes

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3181419/14578, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/431615/31097.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a cross-post from a whole series of questions on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/660169/jarvis-ferns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(((AB)′)′(B+C)+(AB)′(B+C)′)C

=(AB(B+C)+(A′+B′)B′C′)C

=(AB+B′C′)C

=ABC+B′C′C

=ABC

Comment: Not mine, but I suspect it's the lack of words. Welcome to SE.EE too :)

Answer (score 1):

You still messed up your initial statement.

((A NAND B) XOR (B OR C)) AND C

```
((AB)'(B+C)' + ((AB)')'(B+C))C
```

Note it's an AND between the ((AB)')' and the (B+C).

I hope you can get it from there. Still highly suggest making a truth table. It's super obvious what the answer is if you draw out the truth table.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I was unable to create a truth table first, so i finished the simplification.